# how to pass values of several checkboxes with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

To get the value from several checkboxes i use this code:

```
 <form class="myform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="11" /><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="22" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
  </form>
```

The ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.myform').on('submit', function(e){
                //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
                e.preventDefault();
                var checkboxvalue = $('.checkbox').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '',
                    data: {checkboxvalue: checkboxvalue},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.response').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The php:

```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {  

      $value = false;
      if(isset($_POST['checkboxvalue'])){
         $value = $_POST['checkboxvalue'];
      }

      echo 'The value was: ' . $value;
      exit;
   }
```

The problem is: when checking the second checkbox, i get the value `11` ,  thats the value of the first checkbox.
When clicking both checkboxes, i also get the value `11`

What i want to achieve: if i check the first checkbox, het should give me `11` as output. Checking the second checkbox, he should output `22` as value. And when checking both checkboxes, he should output `11` and `22` as value.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: add json stringfy in your ajax data @mudraya

Comment: There will be more that one element with class `checkbox` so look at [jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 3):

USE THIS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.myform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var checkboxvalue =  [];    
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(i){
          checkboxvalue.push( i.value );
        });
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '',
                data: {checkboxvalue: checkboxvalue},
                success: function(data){
                    $('.response').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

the php

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {  
  $value = false;
  /* the check box value in array*/
  print_r($_POST['checkboxvalue']);
  if(isset($_POST['checkboxvalue'])){
     $value = $_POST['checkboxvalue'];
  }      
  exit;
  }
```

Comment: i tried this but is still not working for me.Can you give me **a complete working code** please? So the form, js and php? I am not so familiar with ajax

Comment: unfortunately, still no echo's

Comment: you have to check console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to added name attribute to check

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="value-check" value="11" /><br>

var checkboxvalue = [];
        $.each($("input[name='value-check']:checked"), function(){            
            checkboxvalue.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Comment: i tried this and now the echo is : `The value was: Array`

Comment: @mudraya yes it is an array

Comment: you can use `checkboxvalue.join(", ")` to convert it to coma seperate string

Comment: or you can use `implode(" ",$value);` in php

Answer (score 0):

You need to `loop through` the checkbox which are selected, problem with your code is it is always giving you the value of first selected checkbox always

```js
var chkArray = [];
 
$(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
 chkArray.push($(this).val());
});
 
var selected;
selected = chkArray.join(',') ;

console.log(selected)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox"> Value 1</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="checkbox" checked="checked"> Value 2</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="checkbox"> Value 3</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="4" class="checkbox"checked="checked"> Value 4</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" value="5" class="checkbox"> Value 5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array and fill with the values, if checkbox has been checked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myform').on('submit', function(e){
            //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
            e.preventDefault();
          var values = [];
          $('.checkbox').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              values.push($(this).val());
            }

          });
          console.log(values);
        });
    });
```

See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNNOLo?editors=1111)